# A word or phrase for "misrepresenting someone else's views publicly for personal gain"

Tags: phrases, expressions

The politician claimed that my research showed that I supported the proposition, but really he was just _______ .

Comment: _Exploit_: to use selfishly for one's own ends.

Comment: misattributing ?http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/misattribute

Comment: I was thinking more like: taking something I said and using it in a context it was never intended to be used in, which is one I do not endorse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The politician claimed that my research showed that I supported the proposition, but really he was just **slanting the facts***.

> slant: to interpret or present **in line with a special interest** :  [**angle**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/angle)
>    ; especially :  to maliciously or dishonestly distort or falsify

[**M-W**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slant)

> *In foreign affairs, it has been widely reported that the Bush Administration slanted the intelligence about the possibility of Iraq having weapons of mass destruction.*

[**Free Republic**](http://www.freerepublic.com/focus/bloggers/3172003/posts)

Answer (score 1):

he was just **twisting my position** (to twist means to alter the meaning of something).

Example from [CBSNews:](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/hillary-clinton-dont-twist-my-position-on-gay-marriage/)

> *Hillary Clinton: Don't twist my position on gay marriage*
>
> Hillary Clinton defended her evolution on the issue of gay marriage on
>   Wednesday, impatiently telling an interviewer to stop "playing with my
>   words" after she was pressed to explain her change of heart.

Answer (score 1):

He was just “[**cherry picking**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_picking_%28fallacy%29) or [**picking and choosing**](https://imgflip.com/i/lp0bo) [from] your work/data/words out of context.”

“**Cherry picking**, suppressing evidence, or the fallacy of incomplete evidence is the act of pointing to individual cases or data that seem to confirm a particular position, while ignoring a significant portion of related cases or data that may contradict that position.” (from Wikipedia)

**[pick and choose](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pick+and+choose)** -- “to take only what you want from a group … You cannot pick and choose which rules to accept and which to ignore.” (from The Free Dictionary, citing Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms Copyright © Cambridge University Press 2003)